# How to infer correct types for Cypress?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app, cypress

I have a create-react-app application that I have ejected so I can add `eslint-plugin-cypress`.

I have jest tests and I have also installed cypress.

However, in my Cypress tests my VSCode Intellisense, the types are being inferred as `jest` types and not Cypress / Chai types.

```js
// ./cypress/integration/test.spec.js

describe("My test", () => {
  it("runs ok", () => {
    expect(true).to.eq(true);
  });
});
```

[image]

This "expect" is actually uses "chai".

I've added `/// <reference types="Cypress" />` to the top of the file but it still does not work.

Comment: Do you have a separate tsconfig for the cypress files?

Comment: Also note you don't need to eject to add an ESLint plugin; you can do it with vanilla CRA, if you're on version 4, see e.g. the linting section of https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try `import {expect} from 'chai` or `import {expect} from 'mocha`

Comment: @captain-yossarian this isn't required

Answer (score 0):

For me, following [these instructions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Configure-tsconfig-json) from the docs was sufficient:

> #### Configure tsconfig.json
>
> We recommend the following configuration in a `tsconfig.json` inside
> your `cypress` folder.
>
> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "target": "es5",
>     "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
>     "types": ["cypress"]
>   },
>   "include": [
>     "**/*.ts"
>   ]
> }
> ```

In a vanilla CRA TS app, the definitions VS Code showed for `it` and `expect` in `cypress/integration/demo.spec.ts` were initially:

```
var it: jest.It
(name: string, fn?: jest.ProvidesCallback, timeout?: number) => void

const expect: jest.Expect
<boolean>(actual: boolean) => jest.JestMatchersShape<jest.Matchers<void, boolean>, jest.Matchers<Promise<void>, boolean>>
```

and `expect(true).to.eq(true)` showed a compiler error:

```
Property 'to' does not exist on type 'JestMatchersShape<Matchers<void, boolean>, Matchers<Promise<void>, boolean>>'. ts(2339)
```

but once I'd added the above configuration to `cypress/tsconfig.json` the definitions became:

```
var it: Mocha.TestFunction
(title: string, fn?: Mocha.Func) => Mocha.Test (+5 overloads)

const expect: Chai.ExpectStatic
(val: any, message?: string) => Chai.Assertion
```

---

In terms of ESLint, note that from CRA 4 the configuration is in `package.json`, so you can configure the Cypress plugin as an *override* for the files in your `cypress` folder. For example, as I show in [this blog post](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html) on test-driving a CRA app with Cypress:

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "extends": [
          "plugin:cypress/recommended"
        ],
        "files": [
          "cypress/**/*.js"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```